# Issue with Ajax Appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a comment model that is paginated and I would like the comments to load more comments on the same page whenever the next button is clicked. I have somewhat of an idea of how to go about doing this but can anyone advise how to go about doing this. I have some code already.

For the comment section instead of render I think it may have to be looking for the micropost and its id to find the right comments to append but I am unsure about how to go about tying this all together.

**Pagination JS**

```
$(function() {
  $("#CommentPagin a").live("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

**Show JS**

```
$("#cc").append('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "users/comments" )%>');
```

**Comment Section**

```
<div id='comments'>
  <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
  <div id="CommentPagin">
  <span class="CommentArrowIcon"></span>
  <%= will_paginate comments, :page_links => false , :class =>"pagination" %>
  </div>
<%= render 'users/comments' %>
</div>
```

**Comment Rendering Section**

```
<div id="cc">
<% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
<%= render comments %>
</div>
```

**User Controller**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @school = School.find(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
      respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
     end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I´m a bit rusty with rails so this is somewhat generic answer.

I would load the next n comments from a route / action that renders just your **Comment Rendering Section** as HTML

Just think of it as you where requesting assets from your own API and using them to update the page.

Pagination JS

```
/**
* jQuery 1.7+
* use .delegate() for older versions.
**/
$("#CommentPagin").on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Get data from server - make sure url has params for per_page and page.
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
        // refresh client with data
        $("#cc").append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: With this I would not need the show.js? Also if it isn't too much to ask, how would I go about loading it from a route/action?

Comment: no, this is sufficient as long the request is on the same domain.

Comment: Understood, as for my second question I am unsure of how to get started with my route/action to render this, is it possible that you could help me out?

Comment: I think you could add a custom format (respond_to do |format|) or a param to your controller and use it to conditionally render the partial only. Sorry I cant be of more help here.