# Issue with Rendering Ajax/Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

*Situation*: Currently have a comment model that paginates under a micropost. I am trying to make the next button render comments that belong to the micropost.

*Issue*: I am unsure how to go about making a **route/action** inorder to bring these comments through.

*Codes*: I have some code that I will provide below, if anything isn't right please assist.

All help is much Appreciated.

*References*: [Issue with Ajax Appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594972/issue-with-ajax-appending)

**User Controller**

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost = Micropost.new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @micropost.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.order('created_at DESC').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

**Pagination JS**

```
$("#CommentPagin").on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Get data from server - make sure url has params for per_page and page.
    $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
        // refresh client with data
        $("#cc").append(data);
    });
});
```

**Comment Section**

```
<div id='comments'>
  <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
  <div id="CommentPagin">
  <span class="CommentArrowIcon"></span>
  <%= will_paginate comments, :page_links => false , :class =>"pagination" %>
  </div>
<%= render 'users/comments' %>
</div>
```

**Comment Rendering Section**

```
<div id="cc">
<% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
<%= render comments %>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
  has_many :comments
end
```

**Micropost Model**

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end
```

**Comment Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :user_id, :micropost_id
  belongs_to :micropost, :counter_cache => true
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :school
end
```

**Routes.rb**

```
kit::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages
  resources :application
  resources :schools
  resources :microposts
  resources :comments
  resources :users
  resources :sessions
  resources :password_resets
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :users do
      member do
        get :following, :followers
      end
  end
  resources :microposts do
    member do
      post :vote_up, :unvote
    end
  end
  resources :microposts do
    member do
      post :upview
    end
  end
  resources :microposts do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :schools do
    collection do
        get :mostrecent
        get :mostdiscussed
        get :highestrated
        get :viewcount
    end
  end

  match "/users/:id/personalstream" => "users#personalstream"
  match "/schools/:id/mostrecent" => "schools#mostrecent"
  match "/schools/:id/mostdiscussed" => "schools#mostdiscussed"
  match "/schools/:id/viewcount" => "schools#viewcount"
  match "/schools/:id/highestrated" => "schools#highestrated"  
  match "/schools/:id", :to => 'schools#show', :as => "school"
  match "/microposts/:id/comments" => "microposts#comments"
  match "/microposts/:id/upview" => "microposts#upview"
  match "/microposts/:id/vote_up" => "microposts#vote_up"
  match "/microposts/:id/unvote" => "microposts#unvote"
  get "log_out" => "sessions#destroy", :as => "log_out"
  get "sign_in" => "sessions#new", :as => "sign_in"
  get "sign_up" => "users#new", :as => "sign_up"
  get "home" => "users#home", :as => "home"

  root to: "schools#index"

end
```

Comment: what are you doing in the user controller? you are setting @comment 3 times... and why/ how do users, comments and schools share the same id? i dont get what you want to do...

Comment: @klump I update the controller sorry, um what I want to do is make that Pagination JS render out the comments onto the user show page through an route/action but I am unsure how to go about doing this, sorry for the confusion

Comment: so when the user clicks on the div with it "CommentPagin" you want to display the comments? all at once?

Comment: @klump It would be ideal to show all of the comments, trying to go for a facebook comment style

Comment: i will try to come up with something. :D what is the database relationship between user and comments? how to find all comments you want to display?

Comment: is it user -> miniposts -> comments?

Comment: @klump I added the models for user, micropost and comment and for the micropost, I am trying to find the comments that belong to each micropost

Comment: could you post your routes.rb?

Comment: @klump Routes.rb has been posted

Comment: @klump I believe this is the concept but can you take a look at my comment below?

Comment: @klump I took the `Comment Rendering Section` and I put it into the `/microposts/comments` and when I open the site for `/microposts/micropost.id/comments` nothing is there and when I press the next button, it links to page 2 of the users page

Comment: whats in your view? and can you make sure @comments isnt just empty? about the next button i guess that its wired up with the pagination stuff... dont know what to do about this....

Comment: @klump The @comments is rendering out `comments/comment` which is the template for the comments and in my view it is the `Comment Rendering Section` above, and the next button, shouldn't it be just rendering the comments through ajax, isnt that button doing that?

Comment: yeah, it should do. i have no idea why not. i meant if @comments in the controller is empty because than you would not get anything displayed i guess. mhh and how do you create the button?

Comment: @klump The button is just the `next button` pagination creates automatically

Comment: thats why i think its wired up with the pagination stuff and showes the next site. try adding your own button.

Answer (score 1):

add a new action to the microposts controller:

```
app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb
def comments
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @micropost.comments

  # we dont need all the html head stuff
  render :layout => false
end
```

write a view (app/views/microposts/comments.html.erb) where you display all the @comments as you want

and add a new member to you microposts resource `get :comments`

now you can try in the browser /microposts/(add a micropost id here)/comments
this should deliver you all the comments for the user and format them as you wish.

the last part is the simplest: when the user clicks on the div, make a request to this site via ajax and attach the answer to the div where you want to display the comments. the code could look like this:

```
$("#CommentPagin").click( function(){
  $("#CommentPagin").load( "<%= micropost_comments_path( @user ) %>" );
});
```

hope you got an idea. report back if its not working

Comment: Sorry if I confused you but I am trying to get all the comments for specific mircoposts rather than all the comments that the user posted. If I could I would post a picture of the site but like facebook, when a post is posted there is a comment section and once it has a couple of comments underneath it shows the next button that displays all the comments for that post, how can I render the rest of the comments for that micropost. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: I will try this out and message you if there are any issues, thank you so much :), the logic behind this is to render out all the comments for a micropost on a page and then taking these comments and rendering it from that page right?

Comment: almost. i search all the comments for a micropost. then they get rendered into html. this gets fetched via the ajax request and just attaced into the div.